# ion-select with form builder doesn't show correct value

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, ionic4

*.html*

```
 <ion-select formControlName="type">
    <ion-select-option value="t?.id" *ngFor="let t of (issueTypes$ | async)?.result;"> {{t?.name}}
   </ion-select-option>
  </ion-select>
```

*.ts*

```
  init() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      type: ['', Validators.required],
     });
  } 

 save() {
   const maintenance: Maintenance = {
      type: this.form.value.type,
     };
  }
```

*Debug*

[image]

Why `type` shows `t?.id` as value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to bind the value. like so

```
<ion-select-option [value]="t?.id" *ngFor="let t of (issueTypes$ | async)?.result;"> {{t?.name}}
```

also: i think you need to fetch your form data as:

```
this.<FORM>.get('<FIELD>').value
```

Several other items need to be set correctly in order for this to work.  please post full form code if you need more assistance

Comment: Thanks. The issue was `binding`.